# How to divide an alphabetical list into 3 column alphabetical list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, importrange

I have 2 google sheets, one with an alphabetical order names and numbers for each name like: Dean 1 1 1 1, Jacob 2 2 2 2, Kyle 3 3 3 3. I want to transfer all that into another google sheet that has 3 columns, in one is Dean, in one Jacob and in the other one Kyle. I'm trying to a formula that would see a match for their names and place 1 1 1 1 for Dean, 2 2 2 2 for Jacob and 3 3 3 3 for Kyle.

Photos:

[image: Here]
[image: And here]

You'll find the alphabetical list in one column in the "Project Automation Final Result" in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QrfqAOvIc4XnaJrxk0PMr7pmQp42q2b-V8Bqrzxuchw/edit?usp=sharing

The 3 columns alphabetical list in "Names lists" same link as above.

And I want to insert the Final Result in here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s5yBvEcGFvUiiJTc3K-kQLlCqeOupuGcvqJkZGDmjzY/edit?usp=sharing

Any ideas, suggestions help, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6:A, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1QrfqAOvIc4XnaJrxk0PMr7pmQp42q2b-V8Bqrzxuchw", 
 "Project Automation Final Result!A:F"), {2,3,4,5,6}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]